# How do I optimize a high traffic Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, high-load

I am running a wordpress based site which is now hosted on (mt) under DV-Extreme package 2GB+256MB addon RAM. It a muti author site where people are engaged in writing posts, comments, updating status etc. According to Google Analytics this month traffic

Visitor = 45,764
Pageview = 1,051,186
Visit = 141,447

I have cdn my site, compress the css, used w3 Total cache plugin to optimize my site.

Since last month I am getting several down notice from Pingdom. Right now I am facing more down alert than before. And have to restart my site several time to up again.

Is my hosting resource is not enough? Do I need more resource? or what could be the solution?

Helpful suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe MediaTemple have a problem - See http://serverfault.com/questions/216925/how-to-find-reasons-of-why-site-goes-online-offline

Comment: Can you have a look in the mysql/php/apache error logs for anything relating to connection errors (or lack of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your biggest downfall will be doing this on a virtualised system.  I wouldn't put a high traffic site on a shared host, of any kind.

I'd want a dedicated server, because that way, I could guarantee that I could prioritise the system processes to handle the IO for the website, not having to worry about whatever the server was doing for other users.

MT's dedicated-virtual server sounds like an oxymoron.. Which is it? Dedicated, or Virtual?
You can't have both, unless you're the only VM on a host server, in which case, what's the point?

I'd probably want to scale out, too..  get a pair of servers, do mysql circular replication between them, loadbalance and cache with Varnish.  Back these applications onto a server with fast disks(600GB SAS), and Lots of RAM (16GB+).

RAM is cheap now, and Varnish will use lots of it to speed up delivery of your assets.  You'll notice a massive increase in speed.  DB writes will also be faster because of the faster disks.

Try to keep logging and database partitions on separate disks, so the logging (sequential, mostly) access isn't interrupted by database access (random reads and writes)

Answer (score 1):

That's not really that much traffic for a DV Extreme. Look in MT's own Knowledge Base for tips on how to configure httpd.conf for better performance from Apache.

And give WordPress more memory: add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` to the top of wp-config.php.

Clean out your database by deleting post revisions by running:

`DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'`

optimizing after that and adding define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0); to wp-config.php to prevent future revisions.

Run [MySQLTuner](http://blog.mysqltuner.com/) and make recommended changes to my.cnf and monitor performance changes.